# Перемешать элементы матрицы в python

Tags: python, случайные-числа, map, shuffle

```
from random import shuffle
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9, 10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]
def mat(n):
     return shuffle(n)
print(*map(mat, matrix))
```

Программа должна перемешать элементы вложенных списков, но этот код не работает правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shuffle ничего не возвращает, а изменяет непосредственно сам объект последовательности

```
def mat(n):
     shuffle(n)
     return n
```